# import nodes with 3D coordinate to gephi

Tags: python, visualization, gephi

How to import nodes with 3D coordinate to gephi?

The node file structured like this:

```
index  x    y    z
0    0.21 0.34 0.34
1    0.23 0.35 0.25
2    0.25 0.45 0.65
...
```

There are many nodes(10000+).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather vague. However, assuming that your nodes are saved in a CSV format, and I am encouraging you to do so, then for importing one can go from "File>Import Spreadsheet" and locate the path to the CSV.

For the first three rows of your data I can see something like that in the *Data Laboratory*. Please find detailed instructions [here](https://seinecle.github.io/gephi-tutorials/generated-html/importing-csv-data-in-gephi-en.html#full-csv-version)

[image: Node spreadsheet]

I would suggest that you add some more info about:

1. edges (do they exist?)
2. Do `x`, `y`, `z` correspond to any coordinates? It is rather difficult to influence node positions from within Gephi...

Comment: Yes,  the x, y, z correspond to the coordinates in 3D cartesian coordinates.

Comment: Then this is a good way to import your nodes but I don't think that Gephi supports 3d coordinates. At least not the newer versions